# Creating a next page button on Vuejs 3 with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I want to add a button on my page such that it links to the next page and prev page of the router links. My router setup is as:

```
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'testa' }">TestA</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'testb' }">Testb</router-link>
          </li>
```

I want to make something like this:

```
<button @click="nextPage()> 
<button @click="PrevPage()>
```

Which would go to the next page (testb) in this case and a prev button which would go to the prev page if it exists.

My router's index.js looks like this

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'testa',
    component: () => import('../views/home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    name: 'testb',
    component: () => import('../views/contact.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/testimonials',
    name: 'testc',
    component: () => import('../views/testimonials.vue')
  },
```

How do i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add meta info to the routes, which is nice since all navigation info is in one place.

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'testa',
    component: () => import('../views/home.vue'),
    meta: {
      next: 'testb',
      prev: 'testc'
    }
  },
```

Then in the button methods

```js
methods:{
  prevPage(){
     this.$router.push({ name: this.$router.currentRoute.value.meta.prev})
  },
  nextPage(){
     this.$router.push({ name: this.$router.currentRoute.value.meta.next })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the methods body you the router push method to navigate the given route :

```
<button @click="nextPage"> 
<button @click="PrevPage">
```

```
methods:{
prevPage(){
   this.$router.push({name:'testa'})
},
nextPage(){
   this.$router.push({name:'testb'})
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what if i have more than 2 links? Or maybe i made it dynamic?

Comment: Say i have 10 router-links, and i want to navigate to them using the back and prev button, how would we handle that?

Comment: How are they named?

Comment: Each of them route uses the name we set on the router's index.js file. The naming convention isn't systematic per se.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227886/discussion-between-k1st-and-boussadjra-brahim).